# Why java SSLSocketImpl creates a dummy socket?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, jsse

I am upgrading a socket returned from **ServerSocket.accept()** to *SSLSocket* using the following code:

```
SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket (socket, null, true);
sslSocket.setUseClientMode (false);
sslSocket.setSSLParameters (sslParameters);
```

After doing **sslSocket.close()** I can see that some open file descriptor are left behind on the server. These show up in *lsof* output as follows:

```
292u  sock                0,6      0t0 73633829 can't identify protocol
```

Over time (since this is a server), and client makes lot of connections these open files prevent new connections from happening.

I was trying to find the root cause of this, since the problem doesn't seem to generate from our code, by looking at openjdk code. I can see that while closing SSLSocket the following code flow occurs:

SSLSocketImpl's close -> closeInternal (true) -> closeSocket (true)

Following is the code from closeSocket:

```
if (!isLayered() || autoClose) {
    super.close();
} else if (selfInitiated) {
    // layered && non-autoclose
    // read close_notify alert to clear input stream
    waitForClose(false);
}
```

Since it is layered and autoClose is true, I think it goes inside super.close(). The following is code for close function from super class:

```
public synchronized void close() throws IOException {
    if (self == this) {
        super.close();
    } else {
        self.close();
    }
}
```

So, since self != this, self.close() is called. *What this means the "dummy" socket created internally by SSLSocket is never getting closed.*

First, am I right in this analysis that SSLSocket's internal socket will always be not closed? Is this a bug in Java or is my understanding wrong or am I doing something wrong?

**Edit: (further explanation to answer questions)**

**self** is from Openjdk's code only (specifically *BaseSSLSocektImpl.java*). Let me paste some relevant code which hopefully clarifies:

```
final public class SSLSocketImpl extends BaseSSLSocketImpl {
    SSLSocketImpl(SSLContextImpl context, Socket sock,
            InputStream consumed, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        super(sock, consumed);
        // We always layer over a connected socket
        if (!sock.isConnected()) {
            throw new SocketException("Underlying socket is not connected");
        }

        // In server mode, it is not necessary to set host and serverNames.
        // Otherwise, would require a reverse DNS lookup to get the hostname.

        init(context, true);
        this.autoClose = autoClose;
        doneConnect();
    }
//....
}

abstract class BaseSSLSocketImpl extends SSLSocket {    

    final private Socket self;

    BaseSSLSocketImpl(Socket socket) {
        super();
        this.self = socket;
        this.consumedInput = null;
    }

// ....
}
```

**"Dummy" socket:**

```
public abstract class SSLSocket extends Socket
{
    protected SSLSocket()
        { super(); }

// ...
}

class Socket implements java.io.Closeable {
    public Socket() {
        setImpl();
    }
// This is what I am calling dummy socket which is getting created

    void setImpl() {
        if (factory != null) {
            impl = factory.createSocketImpl();
            checkOldImpl();
        } else {
             impl = new SocksSocketImpl();
        }
        if (impl != null)
            impl.setSocket(this);
    }
}

class SocksSocketImpl extends PlainSocketImpl implements SocksConsts {
 // ...
}}
```

So internally a *SocksSocketImpl* object is created which creates socket (which I refer to as dummy socket for want of better word) in native code.

Comment: What is self? `What this means the "dummy" socket created internally by SSLSocket is never getting closed.` --- What do you mean by this?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful I have added some explanation to the original post. Please let me know, if there is still some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

An `SSLSocket` can be created ether from scratch or layered over an existing `Socket`, via `SSLSocketFactory.craeteSocket(Socket, ...)`. The complication in the code arises to handle both cases. Sometimes the `SSLSocket` needs to close itself, sometimes the wrapped `Socket`, and sometimes neither, depending on whether it is wrapping or not, and if wrapped whether `autoClose` was true.